# Is Albert Messiah's Quantum Mechanics still a relevant book to use for a Quantum Mechanics course?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations

I am thinking of purchasing Messiah's book. How relevant is the material discussed in it? Has anything in the book been proven wrong? If so, what book should I supplement it with, or should I even get it at all (not an opinion, based solely on what is outdated and what is not)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The book is sound. There is new stuff understood, but nothing is wrong and this is what you need to know for the modern stuff.

Comment: The OP doesn't even need to purchase it, given [this](https://archive.org/details/QuantumMechanicsVolumeI). The chunks on node numbers' ordering in energy, 3-d oscillator degeneracies, and oscillator matrix mechanics matrices are priceless and hard to find/use in more modern books. A priceless background resource.